# NestJS HttpModule usage behind a coporate proxy

Tags: nestjs, httpmodule

I'm trying to use **HttpModule** (which uses axios) behind a corporate proxy, but doesn't works despite all the rest (applications and scripts from terminal) can access to outside world.

Any suggestion how to configure it in NestJS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share error details or stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

As Nest's `HttpModule` is just a wrapper around Axios, you should be able to configure the `proxy` option [as described here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1679) when you register and configure the `HttpModule`

Comment: Thanks @Jay, but I already tried the suggested link without success. I'm keep having: _Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 207.241.224.2:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1134:16)_. From what I can understand is that the 'Proxy' is blocking the requests, for any reason which I do not know, when the request is done by Axios, Now why for Axios, is what I need to understand.